# Kubernetes pod is much slower than same image running as docker container

Tags: docker, performance, kubernetes, yolov5

I had a docker image build based on yolov5 with some additional code.

For the same build image, if the image is run in docker using

```
docker run --rm yolo-custom --env my_id=123

output 
Yolo Prediction Done. (0.467s)
```

The prediction for each image takes less than 0.5 using cpu

However, on the same instance where the docker is run, if I create a kubernetes deployment running the same docker image.
The prediction is at least >3s

```
output
Yolo Prediction Done. (3.300s)

Yolo Prediction Done. (11.197s)
```

And, if I run more than 1 instance of the kubernetes pod, the 2nd or 3rd pod will go as high as 40s or more.

Both container are run in the same instance of backend server.

I would expect the kubernetes pod to run close to the time run in a docker container

Comment: Have you checked default cpu allocation settings for both setup?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
For the docker, it's default.
For the kubernetes pod, I have tried both default and requests: cpu: 1, limits: cpu: 2
Either setting the result are not close to 0.5s execution time

Comment: Maybe just another details to add, I try to run the python code directly (native) on the same backend and the performance is closed to the docker.
i.e. ~0.5 seconds